# Working of planetary gear set in electric bicycle

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, mechanisms, bicycles

For mid-drive electric bicycles where the motor is attached to the pedals, it provides helping torque which reduces the force that needs to be provided on the pedal.

So, how does a planetary gear set help with this? Like it only gives torque when we apply force on the pedal and not other times. How?

Comment: But is that torque controlled by the motor controller or is there a clutch?

Comment: Crank torque is measured and motor current added in proportion. A one-way clutch allows pedaling without the motor or at speeds in excess of the motor's maximum speed.